# Tkinter listbox <<ListBoxSelect>> not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

My code has 3 ListBox. I have attached a ListBoxSelect on each of them, so when i click on one listBox it selects the same row of the other listbox.

```
def __init__(self, master, lists):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.lists = []
    for column,size in lists:
        frame = Frame(self); frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        Label(frame, text=column, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
        lb = Listbox(frame, width=size, borderwidth=1, selectborderwidth=1, relief=FLAT, export=FALSE)
        lb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',self.immediately)
        lb.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self.lists.append(lb)

def immediately(self, e):
    #Find the element
    for elem in self.lists:
        num = elem.curselection()
        if len(num) == 1:
            break
    #Unselect every element
    for elem in self.lists:
        elem.selection_clear(0,elem.size())
    #Select elements in the same row
    for i in range(self.lists[0].size()):
        for elem in self.lists:
            elem.selection_set(num[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window = Tk()
   window.title("Account Manager")
   window.resizable(0,0)
   window.geometry('+100+200')
   accountList = MultiListbox(window, (('Website', 20), ('Account Name', 20), ('Password', 20)))
   accountList.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)
   accountList.loadListFromFile()
   window.mainloop()
```

On First click (no matter on what listbox) it works perfect. On second click, it just works on the first listBox, on the other two nothing happens.

Why this ain't working on second click on the other listbox?

Thanks.

Comment: Try printing out what `num[0]` is in `immediately`. My guess is, it's not what you expect. Apply basic debugging skills: print out intermediate variables to validate your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you always find the selected item in the first listbox in the first for loop of `immediately(...)` function.  Use `e.widget` (the listbox triggers the function) to find the selected item:

```
def immediately(self, e):
    num = e.widget.curselection()
    for lb in self.lists:
        if lb != e.widget:
            lb.selection_clear(0, lb.size())
            lb.selection_set(num[0])
```